# Sinon multiple stubs in a single test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai

I want to test the **saveRecords** function for the **failure** and before that, I have to authenticate and connect the MongoDB. This is the code.

```
 before(() => {
    sinon.stub(Authentication, 'authenticate').returns(true);
    sinon.stub(mongodb, 'connect').resolves("connected");
    sinon.stub(models, 'saveRecords').throws(new Error("Error while saving record"));
});

it('Should error out if record is not inserted into the mongodb 
  collection', () => {
    orderWebhook(req, res)
    expect(res.result).to.contain("Error while saving record");
});
```

Here is the code I am testing.

```
exports.orderWebhook = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const isAuthenticated = Authentication.authenticate(req);
        if (isAuthenticated) {
        await mongodb.connect();
        await models.saveRecords(req.body");
        res.status(200).send('Saved Successfully!');
        } else {
        res.status(403).send('Error! Auth failed!');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.message);
    }
}
```

I am assuming that this code will stub the authenticate then connect MongoDB and then try to insert the record and throw the error. But it is running **two times** when I debug with the VSCode debugger.

1. The first time it is returning true for the authenticate function and not resolving the MongoDB connect and return to expect immediately.
2. The second time it is running all three properly and throwing the expected error.

It is **failing** when I run the test in the terminal, What could be the issue?

Update: I noticed that the problem is related to the promise. Sinon is resolving the request and I am using **await mongodb.connect();** but it is not working as expected, and if I remove **await** and return **value** instead of promise then it works.

Comment: Your function `Authentication.authenticate` is this `async or sync` check that if its async add await before it.

Comment: It's sync and simply comparing two strings and returning true or false.